# Chain of Responsibility: remainder algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, handler, chain-of-responsibility

In the following method I am trying to do the following:

If you have at least £20:

- Work out the number of £20 notes
- Work out what’s left (remainder) – pass it on to the next handler
- If you have less that £20 – call the next handler

Note: The program is for an ATM dispenser, that dispenses notes (20, 10, 5) dependent on the what (amount) the user needs.

Below is my solution so far, I need help to correct the algorithm

```
@Override
public void issueNotes(int amount) {
    //work out amount of twenties needed
    if(amount >= 20) {
        int dispenseTwenty;
        int remainder;
        dispenseTwenty = amount%20;
        remainder = amount = //call next handler?
    }
    else {
        //call next handler (as amount is under 20)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have another *handler* as field in your class that will *handle* the next work.

Comment: yes but its the algorithm i need help with the calculate the amount of notes, then the amount left over for the next handler...

Comment: Well, imagine how would you do it in real life, then spot the algorithm and code it.

Comment: Note the number of 20's you will give out is `amount/20` (integer division intended) and the amount to pass on the next handler is always `amount%20`

Comment: Yes but im unsure how to put it into code

Comment: Vandale just wrote the code? dispenseTwenty = amount/20; remainder = amount%20;

Comment: Think about the output you want, first. How do you want your method to return the number of notes of each value? An array ? Several methods, one for each type of note?

Comment: I mean im not sure how to set the reminder to the next handler

Comment: DO you have to set it as a return val?

Comment: The word if in the problem statement, if that is the problem statement, is a bit misleading. Think about the quantity it is necessary to calculate, and only write the logic for that. Also, review what a method is.

Comment: I recommend reading the course textbook 'Java Design Pattern Essentials', which is only seven pounds for the kindle!

Answer (score 0):

never mind the syntax, see below:

```
public static final denominators = [20,10,5]

// recursive function

// you can start calling this recursive function with denom_index=0, thus using denominator 20

public void issueNotes(int amount, int denom_index)

{

   int currentDenominator = denominators[denom_index];

   if(amount ==0) return; // no more dispensing

   if(denom_index >2) // remainder drop to below 5

    {

       throwException (" remaining amount not dispensable ");

    }


   if (amount < currentDenominator) // amount less than current denominator

    {

        issueNotes(amount, denom_index+1);

    }

   else

   {

        dispenseNotes(amount/currentDenominator, currentDenominator);

        // call the handler with remainder of the amount and next denominator

        issueNotes(amount%currentDenominator, denom_index+1);

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The chain of responsibility pattern hinges on being able to provide behaviour for handling a requesting message - and potentially dealing with it. If the handler is unable to deal with the request it instead calls the next en-capsuled handler

The two core components would be an interface and concrete

```
interface IMoneyHandler {
    void issueNotes(int money);
    void setNext(IMoneyHandler handler);
}
```

An example of a concrete implementation could be -

```
class TwentyMoneyHandler implements IMoneyHandler {
    private IMoneyHandler nextHandler;

    @Override
    public void issueNotes(int money) {
        int handlingAmount = 20;
        // Test if we can handle the amount appropriately, otherwise delegate it
        if(money >= handlingAmount) {
            int dispenseNotes = money / handlingAmount;
            System.out.println(dispenseNotes + " £20s dispenses");
            int remainder = money % handlingAmount;
            // Propagate the information to the next handler in the chain
            if(remainder > 0) {
                callNext(remainder);
            }
        } else {
            // call the next handler if we can not handle it
            callNext(money);
        }
    }

    // Attempts to call the next if there is money left
    private void callNext(int remainingMoney) {
        // Note, there are different ways of null handling
        // IE throwing an exception, or explicitly having a last element
        // in the chain which handles this scenario
        if(nextHandler != null) {
            nextHandler.issueNotes(remainingMoney);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setNext(IMoneyHandler handler) {
        this.nextHandler = handler;
    }
}
```

Note in the real world you might provide an abstract implementation for this, to avoid code duplication.